# angular 4 nested *ngFor on delete parent error

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem with nested *ngfor in angular 4, what i need to do is delete parent ngfor i have tried with setting it to null and using delete and neither works so i am kinda out of options. basically what happens if you delete parent ngFor angular misbehaves(at least i think) and throws error.

Can you guys help me out and show me the correct way to do nested *ngfor in which it is possible to remove children, or now in angular 4 it is done on some different way?

i have created this test component

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'test-parent',
    templateUrl: './test.component.html',
})
export class TestComponent {
    constructor() {
        console.log("loaded menu");
        setTimeout( ()=> {
            this.data.categories[1] = null;
        }, 1000);
    };
    data = {
        categories: [
            {
                name: 'name 1',
                items: [
                    {
                        name: 'item 1'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'item 2'
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                name: 'name 2',
                items: [
                    {
                        name: 'item 3'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let c of data.categories">
    {{c.name}}
    <div *ngFor="let i of c.items">
        {{i.name}}
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the error, can't read much from it other than it tried to read items of null, if i try delete than same error instead of null of undefined,
 do i somehow need to tell data is changed that part isn't magical any more? If i try this.data.categories[0] = [] or = {} it updates fine the thing is i want to delete data because i want to pass it to server, and because user pressed delete :'( can't believe something like that simply isn't possible?

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of null
at Object.View_TestComponent_1.currVal_0 [as updateDirectives] (TestComponent.html:3)
at Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives] (core.es5.js:12613)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12025)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12340)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12312)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12026)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12340)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12286)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12031)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12340)
at execEmbeddedViewsAction (core.es5.js:12312)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12026)
at callViewAction (core.es5.js:12340)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.es5.js:12286)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.es5.js:12031)
```

Comment: Why not splice the array? Is there a reason that would not work?

Comment: I have tried it it works with this test scenario but tbh i have like 4 nested for loops trough different components, altought it should work i get this same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For removing item from `Array`, you should use `Array.splice(index, length)`.

---

using `delete` will make the item tobe `undefined`, but still there(an item of the Array). same with setting to `null`.
And for your situation, this will leads to error `cannot find something of null/undefined`

Comment: thank you so much it worked, i thought i have tried it and didn't work, anyway doesn't delete fully deletes member of array?

Comment: @VjeranMagisterLudi Still have some problem?

Comment: nop it is fixed, i am doing some extensive testing now

Comment: what is the difference between splice and delete array[1]

Comment: @VjeranMagisterLudi As answered, `delete` will make the item of the array to be undefined, but still an element of the array. something like change the pointer from the true value to undefined.